# Php shell_exec wmic problem

Tags: php

I do not know what i am doing wrong. When i run this if statement i get "Wrong" all the time.

Regards.

```
if(trim(shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model')) != "Model Maxtor 6Y080L0")
{
echo "Wrong!";
}else{
echo shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model'); // Model Maxtor 6Y080L0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this command, my output looks like this:

```
Model
WDC WD10 EARS-00MVWB0 SATA Disk Device
```

there is a line break that gets swallowed by your browser when you output your text. You need to test for that line break:

```
if(trim(shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model')) != "Model\r\nMaxtor 6Y080L0")
```

You may have to play around with the line break - maybe it's just a  `\n`, but seeing as it's Windows, it probably isn't.

Comment: I am trying for ages but i have got no luck. I am trying on WIndows using AppServ.

Comment: @baris it's probably an issue with the line breaks. What is your use case - maybe you can simply check for a partial match? `(strstr(shell_exec(...), "Maxtor 6Y08L0")` should work

Comment: i tried this way but still it is saying wrong. $output = shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model');
$newoutput = trim($output);
$pieces = explode(" ", $newoutput, 2);
echo $pieces[1]; // Maxtor 6Y080L0

if ($pieces[1] != "Maxtor 6Y080L0"){
echo "wrong";
}

Comment: @baris why not try `strstr()`? It's more liberal about the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. When i changed the place of trim it worked. `code $output = shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model'); $pieces = explode("\r\n", $output); echo $pieces[0]; // Model echo "<br>"; echo $pieces[1]; // Maxtor 6Y080L0 echo "<br>"; if (trim($pieces[0]) != "Model"){ echo "Wrong"; }else{ echo "OK."; } echo "<br>"; if (trim($pieces[1]) != "Maxtor 6Y080L0"){ echo "Wrong"; }else{ echo "OK."; } `